# Installing a custom RPM hangs when trying to run a post-install script

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, rpmbuild

I'm building an RPM with my own code and am running into an issue where the RPM is hanging when I install it with yum if I try to launch something as part of the post-install script. For some background, this is a virtual appliance where we've replaced the shell with a program with minimal configuration options. Previously, I couldn't get the program to load via the post-install options in my spec file; it causes the 'installing' line during a yum install to hang. I put a bandaid on it by having a reboot occur. I need this menu to load after installation, but everything I've tried results in yum hanging on the 'installing' line. My latest attempt; using the trap command, causes the same hang. Does anyone have any other ideas?

```
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}
%description
Installs the program.
%prep
%setup -q
%install
rsync -ar /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILD/%{name}-%{version}/ /home/makerpm/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.x86_64
find $RPM_BUILD_ROOT -not -type d -printf "%%%attr(%%m,root,root) %%p\n" | sed -e "s|$RPM_BUILD_ROOT||g" > %{_tmppath}/%{name}_contents.txt
%clean
rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
rm -rf %{_tmppath}/*
rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_DIR}/*
%changelog
* Sun Jan 25 2014 - %{version} - Modified menu with trap ability so the first reboot isn't required.
%post
function finish {
/bin/launcher
}
chmod 755 /bin/launcher
cat /etc/shells | grep "/bin/launcher"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
echo "/bin/bash" >> /etc/shells
fi
chsh -s /bin/launcher root
trap finish EXIT
#List of all files to be extracted
%files -f %{_tmppath}/%{name}_contents.txt
```

Comment: What's `function finish...` supposed to accomplish? Why would you add `/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells` if `/bin/launcher` isn't present? Is it really wise to change the `root` account's shell to `/bin/launcher` (I suspect not, and you just might experience horrible breakage if you do)?

Comment: "I need this menu to load after installation" Can you be more specific about this requirement?  What are all the possible ways that the user would initiate this installation process?  By calling 'yum' from a login shell?  By calling 'rpm' from a login shell?  In a typical system, the 'menu' that you just installed will be invoked on the next login.  Is that sufficient?

Comment: @AaronHanson - A custom app installed with the RPM, which has an update option (yum update) from a custom repo. I want to force the program to open when the yum install or update finishes, but forcing a logout would also theoretically solve it. Will try and post a reply.

Comment: @twalberg - Didn't realize the bug, thanks. Its supposed to be /bin/launcher, which is part of the RPM that is being installed. The trap runs the funciton, which is supposed to open the launcher once the post-install script of the RPM is run and that works, but only if I install the RPM with rpm -ivh. If I use yum, it hangs yum on "installing..." unless I remove the trap. As far as changing root's shell, that's the idea. This is a virtual appliance and /bin/launcher provides all the options the person using the virtual appliance will need to configure it.

Comment: @AaronHanson Just tried logout. It failed during the RPM install saying "logout: not login shell. Use exit". I tried that as well, it exits the yum command, but doesn't logout the user.